# Not able to fetch all values after using aggregate framework of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am facing some issue while fetching records from MongoDB using aggregation framework. I am explaining my document below.

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "619b5d2df548d73066b9e42f"
  },
  "DefectStatus": "NONE",
  "LastVerdict": "Blocked",
  "Method": "Manual",
  "FormattedID": "TC9483",
  "Timestamp": {
    "$date": "2020-07-16T08:24:51Z"
  },
  "Name": "L3VPN 1.1 Full Mesh Service Create (End-to-End)",
  "Defects": 0,
  "Project": "Internet-Solutions-IS4-0-Automation",
  "Type": "Acceptance",
  "LastRun": "2020-07-16T08:24:51.096Z",
  "Quarter": "Q32020",
  "TC_Passed": 0,
  "TC_Failed": 0,
  "TC_Blocked": 1,
  "Enrichment": {
    "Theatre": "Thetre1",
    "Region": "Region1"
  },
  "Test_Type": "Functional"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "619b5d2df548d73066b9e430"
  },
  "DefectStatus": "NONE",
  "LastVerdict": "Pass",
  "Method": "Manual",
  "FormattedID": "TC9930",
  "Timestamp": {
    "$date": "2020-04-22T11:07:58Z"
  },
  "Name": "Check NTP Service is configured & working",
  "Defects": 0,
  "Project": "Internet-Solutions-IS4-0-Automation",
  "Type": "Acceptance",
  "LastRun": "2020-04-22T11:07:58.139Z",
  "Quarter": "Q22020",
  "TC_Passed": 1,
  "TC_Failed": 0,
  "TC_Blocked": 0,
  "Enrichment": {
    "Theatre": "Thetre1",
    "Region": "Region1"
  },
  "Test_Type": "Functional"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "619b5d2df548d73066b9e431"
  },
  "DefectStatus": "NONE_CLOSED",
  "LastVerdict": "Pass",
  "Method": "Manual",
  "FormattedID": "TC9931",
  "Timestamp": {
    "$date": "2020-07-15T13:00:51Z"
  },
  "Name": "L3VPN 1.1 Full Mesh NSO Service - Creation",
  "Defects": 1,
  "Project": "Internet-Solutions-IS4-0-Automation",
  "Type": "Acceptance",
  "LastRun": "2020-07-15T13:00:51.825Z",
  "Quarter": "Q32020",
  "TC_Passed": 1,
  "TC_Failed": 0,
  "TC_Blocked": 0,
  "Enrichment": {
    "Theatre": "Thetre1",
    "Region": "Region1"
  },
  "Test_Type": "Functional"
}
]
```

So this is my document where I am trying to group some fields and fetch the record using the following aggregation framework.

```
db.getCollection('collection2').aggregate([
    {
        "$group":{
            "_id": {
                "Region": "$Enrichment.Region",
                "Theatre": "$Enrichment.Theatre",
                "Customer": "$Project",
                "Test Type": "$Test_Type",
                "Test Sub-type": "$Type",
                "Method": "$Method",
                "Quarter": "$Quarter"
            },
            "TC Passed": {"$sum": "$TC_Passed"},
            "Defects": {"$sum":"$Defects"},
            "TC Failed": {"$sum": "$TC_Failed"},
            "TC Blocked": {"$sum": "$TC_Blocked"}

        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "Region": "$_id.Region",
            "Theatre": "$_id.Theatre",
            "Customer": "$_id.Customer",
            "Test Type": "$_id.Test Type",
            "Test Sub-type": "$_id.Test Sub-type",
            "Method": "$_id.Method",
            "Quarter": "$_id.Quarter",
            "Defects" : "$Defects",
            "TC Passed" : "$TC Passed",
            "TC Failed" : "$TC Failed",
            "TC Blocked" : "$TC Blocked",
            "_id":0
        }
    }
])
```

Here I can fetch all fields but `Region & Theatre` field values are not coming when I am running the above query. I need to group and fetch all the field values those are mentioned inside the `project`. So any expert here can help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: It seems working on mongoplayground. What's the problem? https://mongoplayground.net/p/FU4XGVk8oN5

Comment: @Erenn, as I mentioned `"Region": ","Theatre":` values are not coming and I am using mongo 3.6

Comment: When I test that on my 3.6.21 server, I get `{ "Region" : "Region1", "Theatre" : "Thetre1", "Customer" : "Internet-Solutions-IS4-0-Automation", "Test Type" : "Functional", "Test Sub-type" : "Acceptance", "Method" : "Manual", "Quarter" : "Q22020", "Defects" : 0, "TC Passed" : 1, "TC Failed" : 0, "TC Blocked" : 0 }
`